# Updated Spring-2.5.5 to spring-3.2.3-RELEASE and now i am getting Class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, classnotfound

and the exception i am getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'esbJmsEnvironment': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/metadata/Attributes
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
```

Comment: Please post the full stracktrace, dependencies. Currently there is too little information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This class has been removed from Spring Framework: See the [upgrade guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/apas02.html#api-report-metadata)

Comment: then , what is the alternative/solution to this problem ?

Comment: what is the code you are using this class for anyway. Spring removed it because its use is outdated.

Comment: <util:map id="esbJmsEnvironment">
  <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="${jms.factory.initial}" />
  <entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="${esb.jms.provider.url}"/>
  <entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="${esb.jms.user.name}"/>
  <entry key="java.naming.security.credentials" value-ref="jmsPwd"/> <!--  Injecting password bean  -->
 </util:map>